# predefined condition calculates at first time only

Tags: c, gpio

I've implemented a function which must perform the action then button was pressed and released.

```
void debouncedAction(bool condition, void (* action)()) {
    if(condition) {
        HAL_Delay(DEBOUNCE_TIME);
        if(condition) {
            while(condition) {
            }
            action();
        }
    }
}
```

Predefined condition is

```
#define BTN_PUSHED              (HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(BTN_PORT, BTN_PIN) == GPIO_PIN_SET)
```

While debugging I was found that condition does not calculated each time (as I thought) but only at the first call. Therefore while cycle becomes infinite. Where is the error?

Comment: If you have the chance to change the electronics, you may want to consider using an RC circuit to debounce a button in hardware.  Jack Ganssle has a nice article on [debouncing](http://www.ganssle.com/debouncing-pt2.htm) on his web site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the answer provided by Joachim is correct, this may provide a little more light.  When you make the call to the debounce routine it will probably look like this (I have assumed that you have a function called `onButtonAction` to handle the 'action'):

```
debouncedAction(BTN_PUSHED, onButtonAction);
```

The pre-compiler will substitue the body of the BTN_PUSHED macro in this line:

```
debouncedAction((HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(BTN_PORT, BTN_PIN) == GPIO_PIN_SET),
    onButtonAction);
```

So the `(HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(BTN_PORT, BTN_PIN) == GPIO_PIN_SET)` condition is evaluated and passed to the function 'by value'.

If the 'debouncedAction' function needs to be generic, consider passing a function pointer as the condition argument, in the same way as the action argument.

```
void debouncedAction(bool (* condition)(), void (* action)())
```

And then define a function to test the GPIO state:

```
bool buttonPushed(void){ return BTN_PUSHED; }
```

The call to the `debouncedAction` function now looks like this:

```
debouncedAction(buttonPushed, onButtonAction);
```

Answer (score 3):

The "error" is that the expressions used when calling a function are evaluated only once, and the result of that expression is passed as the value of the argument. That's how *pass by value* works, it passes a single value.

If you want an expression to be called multiple times within a function, you should probably make the condition a pointer to a function that can be called, like your `action` argument.

Answer (score 0):

Working version is

```
void debouncedAction(bool (* condition)(), void (* action)()) {
    if(condition()) {
        HAL_Delay(DEBOUNCE_TIME);
        if(condition()) {
            while(condition()) {
            }
            action();
        }
    }
}
```

or

```
void debouncedAction(bool (* condition)(), void (* action)()) {
    if(!condition()) {
        return;
    }
    HAL_Delay(DEBOUNCE_TIME);
    if(!condition()) {
        return;
    }
    while(condition()) {
    }
    action();
}
```